# Find serial number of child respectively to a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can I find a serial number of a child respectively to a specific class in div?

For example I have

```
<div>
<div class="red">First</div>
<div class="blue">Second</div>
<div class="red">Third</div>
</div>
```

How could I find out that div with text `Third` is second div with class "red"?

Comment: For example, if I try index() I will get 3, but it is 2 what I need here.

Comment: What is use case for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the index within a collection apply [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method on the collection and provide element as an argument. Or apply the method on the jQuery element object and provide the collection selector as the argument of the method.

```js
console.log(
  $('.red').index($('.red:contains(Third)')) + 1
)

// or the reverse

console.log(
  $('.red:contains(Third)').index('.red') + 1
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="red">First</div>
  <div class="blue">Second</div>
  <div class="red">Third</div>
</div>
```

**FYI :** You need to add `1` with the index since index starts from `0`.

Comment: It is not what I need, I need the index() of red class with respect to only red classes.

Comment: For example, here I need two.

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov, please take a look at my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: But it is a bit not enough. What if I will have two divs with class red and text Third and I will need to know the index of the second one with respect to red class?

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov : `$('.red').index($('.red:contains(Third):last'))` , you just need to provide the element as second argument.... this would return the element index in the collection

Comment: But it is not enough as well. In my program I have to obtain such indexes dynamically and I can`t say for sure what index is it. It can be the last as well as the first.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. I will try to provide it as argument.

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov : whatever it is..,, provide it's object as argument